# Unity Legacy Shader how to change decal from script

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, decal

This is what I am using but I can't find anything online regarding how to go about changing out a decal.

Let's consider that I have multiple Textures ex.(Tex1, Tex2, .. etc).

- How could I access the _DecalTex in script so I can assign different textures?
- Like if button selected Change _DecalTex == Tex2, there should be some simple way I just dont know about or have found yet, any help or links to this would be helpful Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of [`LegacyShaders/Decal`](https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Decal.shader)(state Unity 2017.2) you see that the property you want to change is called `_DecalText`

```c#
Shader "Legacy Shaders/Decal" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _DecalTex ("Decal (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

    ...
}
```

You can simply set it using [`material.SetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html)

```c#
material.SetTexture("_DecalTex", texture);
```

e.g. like

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference in the Inspector
    public Texture texture;

    private void Start()
    {
        var renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        var material = renderer.material;

        material.SetTexture("_DecalTex", texture);
    }
}
```

[image]